# Why MPEG-2 Encoder decreases fast in Mbit/s

Tags: multimedia, encoder, mpeg-2

I'm trying to understand how the MPEG-2 works, so I can finish a project which is based on it. First of all I want to understand the MPEG-2. I want to know why the total Mbit/s decreased very fast between 1995 and 2005? It went from 6 Mbit/s to 2 Mbit/s. How was this possible?

[image]

Comment: you realize there's not just one mpeg encoder out there? How should we know why this particular one slowed down?

Comment: Its the MPEG2 (H.262), and there are always created better encoder for the bit reduction. But is this the only reason why the Mbit/s decreased?

Comment: @MarcB It didn't slow down :) The graphic means the bitrate required to obtain the same image quality has decreased over time due to encoder advancements rather than changes in the standard (they did happen). This is usually achieved at the expense of increased computational complexity.

Comment: Thanks for the answer